# How to define a desired axiom environment?

Tags: theorems

First a MWE and its output are as follows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\makeatletter
\newtheoremstyle{myaxiom}%
{0.3\baselineskip plus 0.2ex minus 0.1ex}%
{0.3\baselineskip plus 0.2ex minus 0.1ex}%
{\itshape}%
{}%
{}%
{}%
{1em}%
{\bfseries\thmnote{#3}}%
\makeatother

\theoremstyle{myaxiom}
\newtheorem{axiom}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{axiom}[Axiom of Choice{ \normalfont (Zermelo, E., 1904)}]
Any collection of nonempty sets has a choice function.
\end{axiom}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you see, I define an axiom style in which there is only `\thmnote` in the theorem head. If I want to get the output as the picture, I have to input the codes as above. It has a disadvantage: I have to do more setting when I input the notes. So my question is:

> **Is there any way to define a new axiom environment with two arguments of which one is for the axiom name and of which another is for its note?**

I have tried the following way.

```
\theoremstyle{theorem}
\newtheorem*{axiomofchoice}{Axiom of Choice}
```

But when I write a new axiom, I have to define a new command like that, and so please ignore that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most natural way, in my opinion, is to set the label when the environment is called.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheoremstyle{myaxiom}
  {0.3\baselineskip plus 0.2ex minus 0.1ex}
  {0.3\baselineskip plus 0.2ex minus 0.1ex}
  {\itshape}
  {}
  {\bfseries}
  {}
  {1em}
  {\thmname{#1}\normalfont\thmnote{ (#3)}}%

\theoremstyle{myaxiom}
\newtheorem*{myaxiom}{\myaxiomname}
\newcommand{\myaxiomname}{}
\newenvironment{axiom}[1]
 {\renewcommand\myaxiomname{#1}\myaxiom}
 {\endmyaxiom}

\begin{document}

\begin{axiom}{Axiom of Choice}[Zermelo, E., 1904]
Any collection of nonempty sets has a choice function.
\end{axiom}

\begin{axiom}{Axiom of Choice}
Any collection of nonempty sets has a choice function.
\end{axiom}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Also a good solution! Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2):

Sure, there are a variety of ways to accomplish that. Here's one way that allows for both having a note, and not having one:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheoremstyle{myaxiom}%
{0.3\baselineskip plus 0.2ex minus 0.1ex}%
{0.3\baselineskip plus 0.2ex minus 0.1ex}%
{\itshape}%
{}%
{}%
{}%
{1em}%
{\bfseries\thmnote{#3}}%

\theoremstyle{myaxiom}
\newtheorem{axiom}{}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{namedaxiom}{mo}{
    \IfNoValueTF{#2}{%
    \begin{axiom}[#1]}{%
    \begin{axiom}[#1{ \mdseries(#2)}]}
}{
    \end{axiom}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{namedaxiom}{Axiom of Choice}[Zermelo, E., 1904]
Any collection of nonempty sets has a choice function.
\end{namedaxiom}

\begin{namedaxiom}{Continuum Hypothesis}
There is no cardinal number between $\aleph_0$ and $2^{\aleph_0}$.
\end{namedaxiom}


\end{document}
```

Comment: But it has a problem: when it doesn't have the second argument or the second argument is empty, it will produce errors or print ().

Comment: Didn't realize you needed to allow for that. I've edited my answer to create a form that makes the second argument optional.

Comment: Now it's perfect! Thanks very much!

Comment: By the way, how to pronounce your surname "Klement"?

Comment: Well, that's a new one. Were you googling me or something? I think I say "Klemm ent"? I think in IPA it would be klˈɛmənt? But I've even had family members pronounce it different ways and I don't mind much how exactly it's said.

Comment: [ˈklɛmənt] more accurately?

Comment: I think so? I don't really know IPA; I'm just trusting some online converters, but sounds right, yeah.

Comment: But it seems that [ˈklɛment] is the right one.

Comment: If you think so, you're probably right. I'm not sure I can even tell the difference.